# How did the lights of the lampstand light up only the front area? Numbers 8:1-3

Tags: numbers, temple

Numbers 8:1-3 NIV

> 1 The Lord said to Moses,
>
> 2 “Speak to Aaron and say to him, ‘When you set up the lamps, **see that all seven light up the area in front of the lampstand.**’”
>
> 3 Aaron did so; he set up the lamps so that **they faced forward** on the lampstand, just as the Lord commanded Moses.

Light emits in all directions unless there is a reflector, how to understand vv8:2 that the Lord specific command it lit up a particular direction?

vv8:3 says Aaron set up the lamps so that 'they faced forward', which seems that the light cups can tilt, that is impossible for they burn with oil. What does it mean 'they faced forward'?

[image]

Comment: From a physics standpoint, the light is being reflected off of the side of the Tabernacle into the Holy area which is technically in front of the lampstand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP notes: “vv8:3 says Aaron set up the lamps so that 'they faced forward', which seems that the light cups can tilt, that is impossible for they burn with oil.”

While the cups that hold the oil cannot tilt, depending on the shape of the cup, each cup or the wick in it could be positioned so that the wick/flame points in a certain direction. What that direction is, however, is a topic of some debate among Jewish interpreters. These interpretations can be arranged into two groups.

According to one view, “the face (Strong’s Hebrew [6440](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6440.htm)) of the lampstand” means the front of the lampstand. As shown in the drawing from the OP’s question, the lampstand is understood to be positioned east to west with the wicks pointing in the direction of the shewbread table on the north or opposite side.

> Ibn Ezra understands the expression אֶל־מוּל֙ פְּנֵ֣י הַמְּנוֹרָ֔ה to
> mean “at the front of the Menorah” and he reads this verse in light of
> another verse about the Menorah back in Exodus 25:37, which states,
> “Make its seven lamps—the lamps shall be so brought up as to give the
> light עבר פניה(on its front side).” For him, this expression qualifies
> the last clause and thus Numbers 8:2 should be read as follows:
>
> “When you bring up the lamps, let the seven lamps give light at the
> front of the Menorah”.
>
> In that sense, the passage in Numbers reinforces what has already been
> said in Exodus, that Aaron needs to make sure to point all the seven
> lamps forward, as Jacob Milgrom explains, “for maximum illumination of
> the altar of incense and the table of the bread of presence.” – “How
> should one shine one’s light,” Rabbi Lederman, [jtsa.edu](https://www.jtsa.edu/torah/how-should-one-shine-ones-light/)

Another interpretation has “the face of the lampstand” referencing the central stem. Rather than pointing to the front or away from the lampstand, the lamp or wicks point toward the center or middle lamp or stem.

> According to the opinion that the lamps were positioned from north to
> south (parallel to the Parochet), the three on the southern side of
> the main shaft — the middle lamp — were bending to north and the three
> on the northern side of the main shaft — middle lamp — were bending
> southward. And the light of the wick of the middle lamp tilted toward
> the Holy of Holies.
>
> And according to the opinion that they were positioned from east to
> west (perpendicular to the Parochet), the three on the west were
> facing the middle, the three on the east were facing toward the middle
> lamp, and the wick of middle lamp pointed upward. Thus, according to
> both opinions, “to the face of the Menorah,” meant the middle lamp. –
> “The Menorah,” Rabbi Bogomilsky, [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2829923/jewish/The-Menorah.htm)

Significant to the OP’s question, I think, is the fact that the light represents the presence of God.

> “Did G‑d need its light?” the Talmud asks rhetorically. “Rather it
> testified to all inhabitants of the earth that G‑d’s presence dwells
> amongst Israel.” – “14 Facts About the Menorah in the Holy Temple,” Posner, M., [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5154289/jewish/14-Facts-About-the-Menorah-in-the-Holy-Temple.htm)

While both interpretations have merit, as a symbol of God’s presence, the outward orientation of the lamps and the relationship between the light and the physical space around it loses relevance somewhat. Though the idea of the lamps directing their light to the front does not preclude spiritual meaning, I am drawn to the one that has the lamps pointing toward the middle. The way that they are directed to one central point serves as a moving illustration of their relationship to the inner source of light.

Comment: Your answer is enlightening. Will it be possible the wick while soaking in oil, have the tip place near the front or even tip over the edge of the front of the light cup, so that it shine more area to the front?

Comment: I believe so. Consider these lamp designs at [windowintothebible.com](https://www.windowintothebible.com/about1#:~:text=The%20earliest%20oil%20lamps%20from%20the%20Biblical%20world,would%20hold%20the%20wick%20in%20place%20more%20effectively.)

Answer (score 1):

The translation, "faced forward" is debatable.  The menorah was placed near the south wall of the tabernacle.

Many versions appear to give confusing translations of Num 8:3 such as:

- NASB: Therefore Aaron did so; he mounted its lamps at the front of the lampstand, just as the LORD had commanded Moses. [Aaron mounted lamps in front of the lampstand??]
- ESV: And Aaron did so: he set up its lamps in front of the lampstand, as the LORD commanded Moses.  [Again, Aaron mounted lamps in front of the lampstand??]

The least confusing translation (the Hebrew is a bit confusing) is given by those similar to the CSB (see also HCSB, ASV, KJV, etc):

> So Aaron did this; he set up its lamps to give light in front of the
> lampstand just as the LORD had commanded Moses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been thinking, since the lampstand has seven lights across, it is the brightest only in two directions, the front and the wall and only the front light for people. So when the light already bright to shine forward, why would the Lord emphasize it? Would it be possible Aaron will put the lampstand with the lights perpendicular to the wall? That is, turning the lampstand 90 degree to the figure shown.

Comment: We are not told.  There is speculation that the almond blossom cups had a front and back and that they were higher at the back and thus projected the light forward.  But this is speculation.